# Caffe2 cannot find the CUDA libraries

Tags: android, c++, windows, cmake

For my project, I am trying to integrate a c++ library into an Android app. This library uses PyTorch.

For the first test implementation I used the example from https://github.com/ademar111190/CppAndroidIosExample and try to add my PyTorch Lib.

Building it outside of Android Studio worked, but as soon as I build it internally the error comes up:

```
Your installed Caffe2 version uses CUDA but I cannot find the CUDA
  libraries.  Please set the proper CUDA prefixes and / or install CUDA.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/DEV/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:40 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)
```

I compared both builds in the cmake-gui and found that the Android build was missing the CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR entry.

---

**Solution attempts**

**1:**

I tried to enter the whole thing via the GUI, however when generating outside of Android Studio the error came up:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
log-lib
    linked by target "native-lib" in directory
```

**2:**

I try to add the PATH to Windows, but it did not work

**3:**

I try to add to CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2")
```

---

- *System:* Win 10 64
- *CUDA Version:* 11.2
- *CMAKE Version:* 3.19.2

---

**Changed Files**

*./Android/app/CMakeLists.txt:*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

project(native-lib)
    
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:/DEV/libtorch)

set(Torch_DIR C:/DEV/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch)
set(Caffe2_DIR C:/DEV/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2/bin/nvcc")

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

include_directories (
    ../../CPP/
)

add_library(
    native-lib
    SHARED
    src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
    ../../CPP/Core.h
    ../../CPP/Core.cpp
)

find_library(
    log-lib
    log
)

target_link_libraries(
    native-lib
    ${log-lib}
    ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}
)

set_property(TARGET native-lib PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

if (MSVC)
    file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
    add_custom_command(TARGET native-lib
            POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
            ${TORCH_DLLS}
            $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:native-lib>)
endif (MSVC)
```

Comment: Might be looking for this? https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Comment: @Zsolt CUDA is already installed, but is not found